# doing "nothing" in else command of if-else clause

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

Code:

```
for i in range(1000):
    print(i) if i%10==0 else pass
```

Error:

```
File "<ipython-input-117-6f18883a9539>", line 2
    print(i) if i%10==0 else pass
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Why isn't 'pass' working here?

Comment: Why do you even need `else` in the first place?

Comment: Why not `if i%10 == 0: print(i)` ?

Comment: Are you asking "how do I make this work" or "I'm curious why this [unusual] syntax isn't permissible"?

Comment: this is a small example, i need to extend this on a different problem

Comment: Why isn't this working?

Comment: Dupes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14474168/using-statements-on-either-side-of-a-python-ternary-conditional and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818992/python-ternary-operator-with-assignment

Comment: @Aran-Fey read my question first before marking them.

Comment: @VarenGupta I have, don't worry.

Comment: I found [yet another variation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32954481/why-is-this-simple-conditional-expression-not-working) of the same issue, if you prefer that one.

Comment: @Aran-Fey please save yourself the effort and time to find duplicate answers and read the expected correct answer below by BcK

Comment: Personally in this situation I would use continue as it seems appropriate to use seeing as it’s a for loop.

Comment: @ThomasUpson if you put "continue" instead of 'pass', it will still give syntax error. Try it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is not a good way of doing this, if you see this problem the structure of your code might not be good for your desires, but this will helps you:

```
 print(i) if i%10==0 else None
```

Comment: This definitely makes more sense, but why isn't 'pass' working in this condition?

Comment: It's an expression, not an indented block. @VarenGupta

Comment: Oh, I see. That makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: Yes BcK is right. you use pass for presenting a empty indented block,
pass it not for do nothing. @VarenGupta

Answer (score 2):

This is not a direct answer to your question, but I would like suggest a different approach.

First pick the elements you want to print, then print them. Thus you'll not need empty branching.

```
your_list = [i for i in range(100) if i%10]
# or filter(lambda e: e%10 == 0, range(100))
for number in your_list:
    print number
```